# Testing a function in factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
.factory('Tag', function($window) {

  var Context = {};

  function reset() {
    return Context !== {} ? Context : {};
  }

  return{
    reset:reset
  };
})
```

I have done testing like this

```
describe('method: reset()', function(){
  it('should reset the Context variable', function(){
    spyOn(Tag, 'reset').andCallFake(function(){
      return Context;
    });

    expect(Context).toEqual({});
  });

  afterEach(function(){
    if(Context!== {}){
      Context = {};
    }
  })
});
```

Is, this test is accurate, if yes then why my test coverage is not increasing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling a fake function not the real one, so the code in your actual function is never executed.

your code coverage tool only marks code that was actually hit.

andCallFake is used to mock an external function which you are not interested in testing and you just want some mock response when the code you are actually testing calls it.

your code should make a real call to ...

```
Tag.reset()
```

now if Tag.reset() makes a call to code in another service which you do not want to test then you can use callFake on that call.
Remember this is "unit" testing. The "unit" of code you want to test is the code inside your service, not outside of your service.